Show that $x_{k}$ is the solution of the augmented Lagrangian problem.
Consider the problem of minimizing $f(x)$ such that $h(x)=0$.
Let $x_{k}$ be the global minimum of the aumented Lagrangian problem for certain $\lambda_{k}$ and $\rho_{k}$ and consider that $h(x_{k})=0$.
Show that $x_{k}$ is the solution of the augmented Lagrangian problem.
(FRIEDLANDER, ANA. Elementos de Programação Não-Linear)
My first thought was to show that the second order conditions of the original problem were satisfied when $h(x_{k})=0$, but I couldn't go much further than that.
Anyone can help me with this problem.
$\lambda$ is the lagrangian multiplier.
$\rho$ is the penalty.
(btw, sorry for the bad english, I translated it from portuguese myself).
